# Microsoft Graph API to access SharePoint site navigation

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online, azure-ad-msal

I need to access navigation/quicklaunch items of a SharePoint online site. Unfortunately using MSAL for iOS m only able to fetch access token for either Graph API or SharePoint online API. Is there a way to get these items using Graph API as I do need them for other requests.

Any solutions or advice will be helpful.

Comment: Do you want solution to retrieve sharepoint files using graph api ?

Comment: no, I want to fetch navigation items. which you get from _layouts/15/AreaNavigation of a sharepoint site